# Как передать переменную из шаблона в функцию? Python

Tags: python, django, flask, шаблоны, jinja2

Нужно передать переменную link, которая в цикле, почему функция request.args.get(link) не видит значение переменной link? Как мне это исправить?

```html
{% for link in links %}

<div class="image">
    {% if links[link] == 'photo'%}

        <a href="{{ link }}" >
            <p>
                <img  height="400" src="{{ link }}" alt="">
            </p>
        </a>
        <form action="" method="GET">
            <div display="none">
                <input display="none" type="text" name="url" value="{{ request.args.get(link) }}">
            </div>
```

Comment: Опишите подробнее, что значит "не видит". Код возвращает какую-то ошибку? Код создаёт не тот результат, который вы ожидаете?

Comment: Он передает None

Comment: Так может в request.args просто нет такого ключа?

Comment: {% if links[link] == 'photo'%} странная конструкция... что тут подразумевается?